# Serializing didn't show value

Tags: c#, serialization

EDIT: My attempt to create a simple sample was a failure. I thought I had replicated the issue with my real code, but it was really just a value not set to public, so my serialization was failing.

Original Post:

I have a class with a value to be set on it (A below.) Another class has an A in it and a setter for A's value (B below.) I have a bunch of B's in a list and a series of foreach's and casts. On the inside of it all, I call the setter, but the result of all of this is a list where the setter appears to have never been called. What's going wrong here and how do I get the new value to take?

I was able to recreate the problem in a more simple set of code.

Here's a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4YVHU

Alternatively, here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication28
{
    class A
    {
        public string value = null;
    }

    class B
    {
        private A a = new A();

        public void SetAValue(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Value is set to: {s}");
            a.value = s;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object list = new List<B> { new B(), new B() };

            if ( list is IEnumerable<object> enumerable)
            {
                foreach (var value in enumerable)
                {
                    if (value is B a)
                    {
                        a.SetAValue("blooop");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Serialization.SerializeJson(list));
        }
    }

    // You can ignore this. It's just to more easily display the object result
    class Serialization
    {
        private static JsonSerializer _serializer;

        static Serialization()
        {
            _serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        }

        public static string SerializeJson<T>( T value )
        {
            string jsonString;
            using ( var stringWriter = new StringWriter() )
            using ( var writer = new JsonTextWriter( stringWriter ) )
            {
                _serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
                jsonString = stringWriter.ToString();
            }
            return jsonString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the print statement in the setter is displayed, so I know it's getting in there.

Comment: I don't understand the question / problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Class `B`:
`public A a {get; set;} = new A();`
In order to serialize, variables must be public.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4YVHU

Comment: Ah, dang... Well, that works, but that really just means I failed to replicate the real issue in a simple way. Back to the broken code... it's been a long day...